# How to get Implicit parameter into an anonymous function

Tags: scala

How do I get the implicit val myConnection into scope of the execute(true) function

```
def execute[T](active: Boolean)(blockOfCode: => T): Either[Exception, T] = {
  implicit val myConnection = "how to get this implicit val into scope"
  Right(blockOfCode)
}



execute(true){
// myConnection is not in scope
  useMyConnection()   // <- needs implicit value
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this directly. Is the value of `myConnection` really not determined before you call `execute`? In this case, you could do this:

```
def execute[T](active: Boolean)(blockOfCode: String => T): Either[Exception, T] = {
  val myConnection = "how to get this implicit val into scope"
  Right(blockOfCode(myConnection))
}

execute(true) { implicit connection =>
  useMyConnection() 
}
```

Basically, you pass a parameter to the evaluated function, but then you have to remember to mark it implicit at the call site.

If you have several such implicits, you may want to put them in a dedicated, “implicit provider” class. E.g.:

```
class PassedImplicits(implicit val myConnection: String)

def execute[T](active: Boolean)(blockOfCode: PassedImplicits => T): Either[Exception, T] = {
  val myConnection = "how to get this implicit val into scope"
  Right(blockOfCode(new PassedImplicits()(myConnection)))
}

execute(true) { impl =>
  import impl._
  useMyConnection() 
}
```

If you want to avoid the `import`, you can provide “implicit getters” for each of your fields in `PassedImplicits` and write something like this, then:

```
implicit def getMyConnection(implicit impl: PassedImplicits) = impl.myConnection

execute(true) { implicit impl =>
  useMyConnection() 
}
```

Comment: Jean, its looks very good except that my return value Either[Exception,T] is now expected to be Either[Exception,(Connection)=>T]. Is there any way to keep the return value   Either[Exception,T] ?

Comment: The current code will always return a `Right` or throw, never return `Left`. Maybe you want something like `try Right(blockOfCode(new PassedImplicits()(myConnection))) catch { case ex: Exception => Left(ex) }` instead?

Comment: Jean, thank you for your help. I am with you on the try catch block. My problem is that the return datatype of the execute function should be  Either[Exception,T] and not Either[Exception,(Connection)=>T]. How do I retain the correct return datatype ?

Comment: I still don't understand where you see an `Either[Exception,(Connection)=>T]`.